# Import a new font into WPF application MVVM

Tags: wpf, fonts, addition, default

I have file 'resource.xaml' for all the styles. But I need to add a new font file to my project and re-use it instead of default font. How can I add a new font and use it?
I searched the internet and see some methods. but nothing worked for me.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when using a custom font you must respect the following syntax:

```
"/FontPath/FontFileName.ttf#FontName"
```

for exemple :

```
<Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="/Fonts/VLADIMIR.TTF#Vladimir Script"/>
```

where the name of this font is "Vladimir Script".

Comment: Thank you for your answer. and to where I should add this setter?

Comment: put it in your resource dictionary in whatever control you want it to use that font, or if you want it to be set globally :<Style TargetType="{x:Type Window}"> 
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value=".."/>             
</Style>

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem before, and here's how I did it:

1. Create a folder in your solution and add all of the font **.ttf** files in there.
2. In App.xaml, or a resource dictionary, add the following code:

   pack://application:,,,/Path/To/Font/#Name Of Font

Then, you can reference the font resource in your XAML code:

```
<TextBlock FontFamily="{DynamicResource NameOfResource}" Text="Hello World"/>
```